# Can't query nested object using Morphia (MongoDB)

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, morphia

I'm using Morphia 2.0.2 and I'm trying to query the document that I just saved without success.
Right now I've tested this on an Atlas cluster version 3.6.20 and 4.2.10 and both are unsuccessful.

Here you can find the objects involved:

```
@Entity("employees")
data class Employee (
    @Id
    var _id: String? = ObjectId().toString(),
    @Indexed
    var name: String? = null,
    @Indexed
    var foos: MutableList<Foo>? = mutableListOf()
)

data class Foo (
        @Indexed
        var test: String? = null
)
```

I've initialized the datastore this way, since I had also problems with codecs for class `Foo`:

```
// In order to avoid the "Can't find a codec for class com.test.morphia.data.Foo." error
val connectionString = ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://$username:$password@$url/$dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
val pojoCodecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
val codecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry)
val clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
        .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
        .build()
val mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings)
val dataStore = Morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, dbname)
dataStore.mapper.mapPackage("com.test.morphia.data")
dataStore.ensureIndexes()
```

Then I'm saving a document and I try to query it on the foo object:

```
val employee = Employee(
            name = "Marco",
            foos = mutableListOf(Foo("test1"), Foo("test2"))
            )
dataStore.save(employee)
val result = dataStore.find(Employee::class.java)
            .filter(
                    Filters.eq("foos.test", "test1")
            )
```

When the query is executed, I'm getting this error:

> "Could not resolve path 'foos.test' against 'com.test.morphia.data.Employee'."

How am I supposed to query the database this way? I've tried to look at examples, reference and repository, and I haven't found an example about how to perform this.

EDIT: this is how the document looks in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id":"5f998da6bb8014090ae22549",
    "foos":[
        {"test":"test1"},
        {"test":"test2"}
    ],
    "name":"Marco"
}
```

Comment: from what I can see there you are comparing `foos.test` which is a `String` with an object of type `Foo`. Try `Filters.eq("foos.test", "test1")`

Comment: @Alex.T thanks for your comment but the problem occurs with the String too, it was a misplaced copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance that path should work.  Chances are that there are some peculiarities in introspecting kotlin classes that Morphia hasn't been taught to process yet.  If you can file an [issue](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues) or better yet create a [reproducer](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/reproducer) I can take a closer look.

"Full" Kotlin support is on my radar as I am Kotlin user myself but there are likely still corner cases left to explore.  I have a kotlin project that's been using Kotlin for several years now with great success but I don't think it's necessarily doing nested document queries like this.

Comment: I see your point. Is It possibile that support Is now lesser then on previous versions? (Let's say < 1.5)

Comment: My document anyway in the Real Life project Is quite big and I think that I should be able to replicate what I'm already doing with an older version and on mongo itself here. Otherwise I will drop morphia and use the driver directly. I will open and issue with the reproducer when I'll have some free time.

Comment: I wouldn't say the support less by any means.  Like I said, i have a project running on kotlin/morphia 2.0 for at least a year.  I'm just saying you might have hit a wrinkle in the kotlin class/bytecode that I haven't yet.  It *should* work, though, so it might be something else entirely.